# Alarm on inactivity to prevent sleep and theft

Tags: alarm

Is there a way to configure android or install an app that will sound an alarm if the user stops using the phone?

This is to prevent the user from falling asleep in public transport. This is to ensure they get off at the right stop and to prevent theft while sleeping.